# How to hide and show JSTree?

Tags: javascript, jstree

I want to hide the `JSTree` and clear everything related to that `JSTree` file after clicking a button and then show the `JSTree` again after clicking another file.

I used .empty() to hide, but once hid, it doesn't show up again without refreshing the page. So what's the opposite of hide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use ".empty()" to hide. ".empty" is used to remove markup from the specified selector. 
Use ".hide()" if you wish to hide the tree.Using ".show()" will then make it reappear.

Alternatively use "addClass('hide')" to apply a class which sets the display to none of the tree container. Then if you wish to show the tree container again use "addClass("show")" which is a class with display setting set to display:block.